# JAXB unmarshal exclude specific element

Tags: java, jaxb

I know for **@XmlTransient** annotation, but sometimes I need this element and in other use cases I really have to prevent it from unmarshaling, because it contains base64 text. So I need to exclude it because performance problems.

Is there any way to *dynamicly exclude* one element from unmarshaling with JAXB?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be enough for you to have non-trivial setter? JAXB would call the setter and inside you would do something like this:

```
 public void setMyProperty(String myProperty) {
    if (someSpecialBusinessDecision()) { 
        this.myProperty = myProperty;
    }
 }
```

Comment: I've kinda solve problem differently then, but your answer will also come in handy, so thank you!